# Include jQuery in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got two bits of code that I'd like to work together but I don't manage to integrate this jQuery snippet into the JavaScript correctly …

JavaScript:

```
(function(){

// Creates the plugin
tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.mygallery', {

    // Creates control instances based on the control's ID.
    createControl : function(id, controlManager) {
        if (id == 'mygallery_button') {

            // Creates the button
            var button = controlManager.createButton('mygallery_button', {
                title : 'MyGallery Shortcode', // Title of the button
                image : '../wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_mrgreen.gif', // Path to the button's image
                onclick : function() {

                    // Triggers the thickbox
                    var width = jQuery(window).width(), H = jQuery(window).height(), W = ( 720 < width ) ? 720 : width;
                    W = W - 80;
                    H = H - 184;
                    tb_show( 'My Gallery Shortcode', '#TB_inline?width=' + W + '&height=' + H + '&inlineId=mygallery-form' );
                }
            });
            return button;
        }
        return null;
    }
});

// Registers the plugin
tinymce.PluginManager.add('mygallery', tinymce.plugins.mygallery);


// Executes this when the DOM is ready
jQuery(function(){


// Creates a form to be displayed everytime the button is clicked
    var form = jQuery('<div id="mygallery-form"><table id="mygallery-table" class="form-table">\
        <form id="myForm">\
            <div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">\
                Name: <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" />\
            </div>\
            <div>\
                <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="add another name" />\
                <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="remove name" />\
            </div>\
        </form>\

        </div>');

    […]
});
})()
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
            var num     = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
            var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

            // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
            var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

            // manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
            newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);

            // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
            $('#input' + num).after(newElem);

            // enable the "remove" button
            $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','');

            // business rule: you can only add 5 names
            if (newNum == 5)
                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
        });

        $('#btnDel').click(function() {
            var num = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
            $('#input' + num).remove();     // remove the last element

            // enable the "add" button
            $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');

            // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
            if (num-1 == 1)
                $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
        });

        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

FYI: The JS creates a popup with a form (WordPress) and with the jQuery snippet I'd like to implement the feature that the user can add more input fields dynamically.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's your question? Consider using [jsfiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net) to illustrate any errors you may have.

Comment: Just for reference.. There is no difference between jQuery and Javascript. They are in fact the same exact language. However jQuery is a library that is built off of Javascript, so you can easily develop the front end of your applications with little worry over compatibility issues, or having to spend a lot of time writing large chunks of code for what each function within jQuery does with a simple `.functionName()` So Putting jQuery in Javascript or Javascript in jQuery is a redundant question.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the jQuery snippet after your javascript code. That shouldn't be the problem since your jQuery code is merely binding events.

However, I can't tell where #btnAdd and #btnDel are. The problem may be that the elements are created after the jQuery code is run, hence when you called this:
    `$('#btnAdd').click(function(){...});`
the element #btnAdd was not there.

Try this:
    `$(document).on('click', '#btnAdd', function(){...});`

This will bind the click event to document (which is always present) instead of #btnAdd.
To improve the performance though, you should bind it to a parent of #btnAdd that you know for sure is present when document is ready.